# How can I customize the numbering in toc with titletoc

Tags: table-of-contents, titletoc

I am new to `titletoc`.

And I want to have a table of content like:

> I. First Chapter
>     1. first section 
>     2. section section
>       2.1 subsection
>  
>   II. Second Chapter

So I would like to modify the "numbered-entry-format" argument of `\titlecontents` to achieve my goal.

Of all the examples I browsed, only `\thecontentslabel` is used here which, in my case, outputs 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1 (Point is, I want to drop the chapter index).

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
\usepackage{titletoc}
       \titlecontents{chapter}[1em]{\smallskip}%
        {\contentslabel[\MakeUppercase{\romannumeral\thecontentslabel}.]{1.5em}\enspace }
        {}%numberless%
        {\enspace\dotfill\contentspage}[\medskip]%
        %
        \titlecontents{section}[0em]{\smallskip}%
        {\thechapter.\thecontentslabel\hskip0.8em}%numbered
        {}%numberless
        {\enspace\dotfill\contentspage}[\smallskip]%
```

Comment: This achieves exactly what the OP is trying to avoid :-)

Answer (score 2):

Would you also be fine with a simple solution without `titletoc`?

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{cap1}
    \section{First section}
    \subsection{First subsection}
    \subsection{Second subsection}
    \section{Second section}
    \subsection{First subsection}
    \subsection{Second subsection}
    \chapter{cap2}
\end{document}
```

[image]